# Having different character formats PHP / Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, html-entities

On my site i'm trying to get different character support for the searches, for example hebrew so something like

```
אייל גולן
```

but the thing is, when they make the search it's stored in the database like

```
#1488;#1497;#1497;#1500; #1490;#1493;#1500;#1503;
```

What should i do? Is there any way to convert that back to readable hebrew text? or should i find a way to store in the db properly.

Thanks

Comment: If possible, you shouldn't be storing hebrew characters like that: Using UTF-8 as the database table encoding, and using native characters would be better. Why are they going into the database like that? At which point are they turned into HTML entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I wouldn't suggest going down to html_entity_decode(). I would use it as last solution. Make your page and database UTF-8 (character set and file if necessary).

Later if you are using any php built-in functions for html characters, make sure they allow UTF8 also.

This will make you code less and give you less headache.

Answer (score 0):

[html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) could help you out.